# Python dictionary only iterating the last key:value entry

Tags: python, dictionary

```
vin_bag = {}

option = int(input("PLease enter your option: \n"))

while option != 0:
    if option == 1:
        artist = input("Enter artist: \n")
        song = input("Enter song: \n")
        vin_bag[artist] = song

        option = int(input("PLease enter your option: \n"))

    elif option == 2:
        lib_songs = str(len(vin_bag))
        print("There are " + lib_songs + " songs in your music library. \n")

        option = int(input("PLease enter your option: \n"))

    elif option == 3:
        for song in vin_bag:
            print(artist, vin_bag[artist])

            option = int(input("PLease enter your option: \n"))
```

Option 3 iterates only over the last key:value entry and not the entire dictionary, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: There's no "last", you can only have one value for a given key.

Comment: You are using `song` as the index variable, but then only using `artist` (whose value is left over from a previous iteration of the `while` loop). `for artist, song in vin_bag.items(): print(artist, song)`.

Comment: Which is to say, the *iteration* is working fine; you're just *printing* the wrong values.

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you want to move your option input outside the scope of the for loop. Secondly, to iterate through a dictionary use vin_bag.items()

```
elif option == 3:
    for pair in vin_bag.items():
        print(pair)

    option = int(input("PLease enter your option: \n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elif option == 3:

            [print(artist, song) for artist, song in vin_bag]

            option = int(input("PLease enter your option: \n"))
```